# Salesforce formula to exclude holidays between two date time fields

Tags: formula-field, businesshours, holidays

I would like to create one formula field on Case object which calculates business hours between two dates. Weekends, as well as Holidays mentioned in Business hours, should be excluded in the formula. I know the formula to exclude the weekends but how would I remove holidays.

I know the Apex code to query on BusinessHours object but I need formula rather than Apex code.

Comment: I recommend you look at [Guidelines for Setting Business Hours](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_supporthours_guidelines.htm&type=5) and [Guidelines for Creating Support Holidays](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizesupport_holidays_guidelines.htm&type=5). This [kb article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329632&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) might also be helpful.

Comment: this can't be done in formulas; vote up this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpWdAAK). The generalization of the problem is difficult for formulas because you can have holidays in different locales (e.g. India v United States)

Comment: Thank you all. I'll see for any workarounds.